# Mixing onChange and ng-change in select

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

Ok, I know the following code is wrong since it's not working. But hopefully it'll help describe what I'm trying to do:

```
Choose a new background color for the site:&nbsp;
<select name="bgcolor" onChange="ModifyColorsInLess();" id="bgcolor" ng-change="changeCurrent('bgcurrent');">
<option ng-repeat="color in colorlist" value="{{color}}" ng-selected="color==bgcurrent" >{{color}}</option>
</select>
```

Now, you'll see I have two things that I want to happen on a selection.

1) Hit the JS function `ModifyColorsInLess()` which this does and does perfectly. The function is sitting in a regular JS file. This changes the actual value of a LESS variable immediately.

2) Hit the function in the controller of `changeCurrent()`. This is an attempt to change the value of a scope variable set in the Angular controller.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the code do both.

EDIT:
Controller code:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$location', '$sce', '$routeParams', '$timeout', function($scope, $location, $sce, $routeParams, $timeout ) {
// Configuration Variables:
$scope.title = "Site Title";
$scope.logosrc = "images/site_logo.gif";
$scope.tagline = "This is the new tagline!!!";
$scope.bgcurrent = "White";
$scope.pccurrent = "Black";
$scope.sccurrent = "LightGray";
$scope.dtccurrent = "Black";
$scope.ltcurrent = "LightGray";

// This changes the shadowed aspect of the top nav and footer based on a checkbox
$scope.shadowChange = function(cb){
    var isChecked = (document.getElementById('shadow').checked);
    if(isChecked){
        $('#footer').addClass('shadowed');
        $('.nav').addClass('shadowed');
        $('.show-menu').addClass('shadowed');
    }else{
        $('#footer').removeClass('shadowed');
        $('.nav').removeClass('shadowed');
        $('.show-menu').removeClass('shadowed');
    };
    return true;
};
// This converts any HTML code in the text to actual code so that it renders properly
$scope.renderHtml = function(html_code)
{
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};

// This sets a default value for the passed parameter. $routeParams.action in this example
if(!(typeof $routeParams.action === 'undefined')){
    $scope.pageAction = $routeParams.action;
}
else{
    $scope.pageAction = "home";
}

// This changes a default color
$scope.changeCurrent = function(varname){
    alert(varname);
//      $scope[varname] = valname;
};


}]);
```

Comment: if you're just looking to change the current var, you can bind it to `$scope.bgcurrent` by setting `ng-model="bgcurrent"` on the select. This will change the variable automatically.

Comment: it didn't work. 
I tried `<select ng-model="bgcurrent" name="bgcolor" onChange="ModifyColorsInLess();" id="bgcolor">
<option ng-repeat="color in colorlist" value="{{color}}" ng-selected="color==bgcurrent">{{color}}</option>
</select>`

Comment: Can you post the code for your controller?

Comment: // This changes a default color
 $scope.changeCurrent = function(varname){
  alert(varname);
//  $scope[varname] = valname;
 }; (sorry for formatting)

Comment: Sorry--can you edit your question and post it up there? -- also, the whole thing from controller(... to });

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: For the record, when I use ng-model="bgcurrent" it changes the value on the page, but not globally. If I navigate away from the page and back, it's reverted to the default set in the controller.

Comment: Right, bgcurrent is local to your homecontroller, unless you save it somehow--how are you doing that? P.S. Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KDwwX1KkONPakAyvayHg?p=preview

Comment: Right. I've accomplished what you have done in that plunkr. I'm trying to save the new value of bgcurrent across views. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Using the $rootScope is a way of setting and using global variables. updated. You have to add $rootScope to your injectiosn on your controllers. And you use in your views like {{$root.bgcurrent}}.

Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KDwwX1KkONPakAyvayHg?p=preview

Comment: I tried this: <select ng-model="$root.bgcurrent" name="bgcolor" onChange="ModifyColorsInLess();" id="bgcolor">
<option ng-repeat="color in colorlist" value="{{color}}" ng-selected="color==$root.bgcurrent">{{color}}</option>
</select> and injected $rootScope, but it still doesn't persist.

Comment: Are you trying to make it persist across page visits (going off to some other site and coming back)? You're going to have to use $cookies or server storage for that, which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: no. within the site. I'm using it like so: There are several dropdowns to change various less variable colors. The change works, and, as long as you don't refresh the screen, the new colors hold as you navigate. But I want the current color to be the selected item in the dropdown when you navigate BACK to the page. It's reverting to the original value being selected in the dropdown. I'll try to put the site up so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Ok. Even refreshing you're going to need to use a cookie or store it on the server. Or store the bgcurrent in the $routeparams somehow, but that seems pretty superfluous.

Comment: I don't care if I lose it on refresh. I just want it to stay as I click around the site.

Comment: http://www.gelerinter.com/dev_sites/TEMPLATESITE click on Change Style. Change something. Click around. Come back to page. You'll see the dropdowns reflect the original defaults, not the new values.

Comment: GOT IT!!!! My Controller was resetting it every time. I only set it anew if it's undefined.

Comment: Edit: yep, glad we got that sorted.

Original: _Each time you go to a view the controller runs from teh beginning, setting all of the variables you have up top. Try removing  $rootScope.bgcurrent = "White"; and see what happens._